# How to find angle with atan() function in C program?

Tags: c

I wrote a programme to find polar co-ordinates if cartesian co-ordinates are given. But I am not able to get the angle correct pls help?

```
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int x,y,z,r,ang;
  float k;
  printf("enter the cartesian co-ordinates:");
  scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);

  z=x*x+y*y;
  r=sqrt(z);
  k=y/x;
  ang=atan(k);

  printf("polar co-ordinates r=%d,ang=%f",r,ang);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be better to include some details like what inputs you used, what outputs you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: `float k, r, ang;` .. `k=y/r;`

Comment: and `ang` need to modify by the value of `x`.

Comment: I dont understand why this question is downrated?

Answer (score 5):

You should use `double` numbers, not `int` in your case. Read the documentation of [atan(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atan.3.html), [atan2(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atan2.3.html) - it works with radians. And end each `printf`  with a `\n` or else call [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html); also, better test the result of [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html). And it is good habit to initialize the variables (because later your code would become more complex, and you don't want uninitialized values).

```
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
  double x=0.0,y=0.0,r=0.0,ang=0.0;
  printf("enter the cartesian co-ordinates:\n");
  if (scanf("%f %f",&x,&y)<2) 
     { fprintf(stderr,"bad input\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);} ;

  r=sqrt(x*x + y*y);
  ang=atan2(y, x);

  printf("polar co-ordinates r=%f, ang=%f\n",r,ang);
  return 0;
}
```

At last, compile with all warnings and debug info, e.g. with

```
 gcc -Wall -g angconv.c -o angconv
```

if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)

As  [Jonathan Letter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) commented, in the particular case the initialization assignments of `0.0` are useless. But you'll probably improve and grow your code base, so later they could be useful. It is a matter of habit, I usually always initialize variables (the compiler would optimize that and remove it if uneeded). And they make the code more deterministic, you would understand better if you step by step your program in the debugger (e.g. `gdb`)

<sup>When compiling with `gcc -Wall` you'll get a warning for most uninitialized variables.</sup>

Also, you could avoid having `r` and `ang` and use the `sqrt(x*x + y*y)` and `atan2(y,x)` expressions directly in the `printf`.

Notice that `atan2` is better than `atan` since you won't divide by zero if `x` is 0.0.

Comment: All those initializations are slightly pointless; the first time the variables are used, they are set (`x` and `y` by `scanf()`, `r` and `ang` by assignment), so there is no chance to abuse them uninitialized (since you check the return value from `scanf()`). One could even argue that you should not define `r` and `ang` until you can do the assignments: `double r = sqrt(x*x + y*y); double ang = atan2(y, x);`.

Comment: `atan2` is also more accurate for angles close to (2k+1)pi

Comment: The primary reason for `atan2()` vs. `atan()` is that `atan2()` provides a machine -pi to pi range, whereas `atan()` provides half of than: -pi/2 to pi/2 range.  Both approaches have trouble if x,y --> 0,0.

Answer (score 0):

finally i find the solution to the program. thank you for your suggestions.

```
    #include<math.h>
    #include<stdio.h>
    #define PI 3.14159265

  int main()
{
  float x,y,z,r;
  double ang,val;

  printf("enter the cartesian co-ordinates:\n");
  scanf("%f%f",&x,&y);

  z=x*x+y*y;
  r=sqrt(z);

  val=180.0/PI;
  ang=atan2(y,x)*val;

  printf("polar co-ordinates r=%f,ang=%1f",r,ang);

  return 0;

  }
```

Comment: Not fully good but almost. You should use `M_PI` already defined in `<math.h>`, no need to define your `PI`

Comment: `hypot()` has an advantage over `sqrt(x*x+y*y)` as it has less range limitations.